# SQL Server reducing the length of the string to 8000 characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, ntext

I am trying to insert data in a table with column datatype as `NTEXT`. Ideally it should store more than 8000 characters, but the in my case it is reducing it to 8000 characters.

I am making the Insert Query at runtime in Procedure.  Below is the sample query that procedure is making.

```
INSERT INTO TMPRESULTS SELECT ('A' + ',' + 'B' + ',' + 'C')
```

A,B,C, etc. are sample data and actual data will be identified at runtime with actual content crossing 8000 characters. Also the variable used to store the value are defined as '`NVARCHAR(MAX)`'

However, when I try following query it does insert more than 8000 character in the table

```
INSERT INTO TMPRESULTS SELECT ('ABCdddd................')
```

I presume while I am trying to concat the data with '+' sign, sql server is reducing the length to 8000. I can't use `CONCAT` as data will be more than 256 columns/arguments.

Any idea, why it is doing so? Also, if someone can help with some alternate solution as I will have to make insert query at runtime.

Comment: The type of an expression is given by its members, not by the column/variable you will store the result in. If no members of the expression are of type `nvarchar(max)`, the entire expression will not be promoted to `nvarchar(max)` when it calculates, even if the resulting length would be greater than 4000/8000. Cast at least one of the expression members to `nvarchar(max)`.

Comment: HI @GSerg, I have stored the data in NVARCHAR(MAX) which makes up the experssion. Don't know if I should do anything else

Comment: `ntext` has been deprecated for over a *decade*. Beyond time to have upgraded/replaced it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is documented in [+ (String Concatenation) (Transact-SQL) - Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/string-concatenation-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#remarks):

> If the result of the concatenation of strings exceeds the limit of
>   8,000 bytes, the result is truncated. However, if at least one of the
>   strings concatenated is a large value type, truncation does not occur.

For a `varchar` 8,000 bytes would be 8,000 characters, and for a `nvarchar` 4,000.

All your literal strings in the query `INSERT INTO TMPRESULTS SELECT ('A' + ',' + 'B' + ',' + 'C')` are non large value types (In fact, they are all a `varchar(1)`). If you `CONVERT`/`CAST` one of them to a `varchar(MAX)` this would solve the problem:

```
INSERT INTO TMPRESULTS
SELECT (CONVERT(varchar(MAX),'A') + ',' + 'B' + ',' + 'C');
```

if you want an `nvarchar`, make sure you declare your literal strings as a `nvarchar` too:

```
INSERT INTO TMPRESULTS
SELECT (CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX),N'A') + N',' + N'B' + N',' + N'C');
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2017 onwards, there is [CONCAT_WS function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-ws-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to perform concatenation easily. You can also read about [CONCAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

So, instead of this:

```
INSERT INTO TMPRESULTS SELECT ('A' + ',' + 'B' + ',' + 'C')
```

We can have below:

```
INSERT INTO TMPRESULTS SELECT CONCAT_WS(CAST(N',' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),'A','B','C'))
```

I have put sample below from SQL Server 2017 for reference:

```
CREATE TABLE #tempValue(BigValue NVARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO #tempValue
SELECT CONCAT_WS(CAST(N',' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),REPLICATE('A',4000),REPLICATE('B',4000),REPLICATE('C',4000))

SELECT LEN(BigValue) FROM #tempValue -- 12002
```

Also, CONCAT_WS is better for below reasons:

> If CONCAT_WS receives arguments with all NULL values, it will return
>   an empty string of type varchar(1).
>
> CONCAT_WS ignores null values during concatenation, and does not add
>   the separator between null values.

Comment: While using `concat_ws` may look cleaner, it has nothing to do with the truncation problem. `select cast(CONCAT_WS(',', replicate('A', 4000), replicate('B', 4000), replicate('C', 4000)) as nvarchar(max))` will still truncate the result at 8000 characters.

Comment: @GSerg, Thanks. I have updated my answer. If one of the parameters is NVARCHAR(MAX), CONCAT_WS automatically converts the return type as NVARCHAR(MAX)